# SSIS C# WebRequest from non SQL Server

Tags: sql, ssis

I have an issue I am trying to solve but I am not sure if this is possible. I have a SQL Server with SSIS Components installed but the SQL Server is completely locked down without any Internet Access

I have an SSIS Package that uses C# to authenticate with a RestAPI URL and then Parse JSON from two other URLs using the authentication. Currently I am manually executing the SSIS package through an app server that can access the SQL Server as well as internet. But now I need to figure out how to get this package to run on its own.

If I deploy to the SQL Server it obviously wont connect because it cannot access the RestAPI URLs. Are there any options to either get the SSIS Package to run on the App server on its own or be able to have the C# reach out to the app server for internet access first while deployed to the SQL Server.

Any thoughts on how to achieve this? Thanks!

Manually running package on App server runs fine.
Deploying SSIS package to SQL Server without internet returns a unable to connect to remote host

Comment: Can you explain the mechanics behind "Manually running package on App server runs fine"

Comment: I just mean I'm opening the package via Visual Studio 2019 and executing the SSIS package from the App server with internet access and a data connection to the SQL Server. I am just trying to find a way to automate this instead of having to do this method every day.

Comment: Perfect! I wanted to confirm that was the case and not that you had installed SQL Server Integration Services Service on the App server because that'd be a license violation.

Comment: Can the SQL Server talk to the App server? Is it possible to write a relay or something that lives on the app server? It's probably the guts of what you already have in the SSIS package and just have it... emit the data in some convenient manner? Write to file, write to the database, repeat the json so the package can consume it?

Comment: The SQL Server and App server can communicate back and forth to each other. Was wondering if there was some way reach across to run the C# web request from that machine but I am not quite sure what that would look like. Its a bit out of my element